# How not to start a new emulator instance each time when the app executed

Tags: android, android-emulator, appcelerator

i'm using titanium appcelerator for developping an opp on android but i think this question can be answered by any android developper and anyone else using the android emulator.

It's already too long to wait for the emilator to be ready and for me always the first execution which makes the emulator for the first time stops on the "waiting for the emulator to be ready" step and i have to restart the app again and if the new launched app will start a new emulator instance it will be worst.. So is there a way to  force always using the already created emulator instance ?

Answer (score 0):

you mean emulator?

If there is an emulator, it will not start new one .

Do not close it .

Comment: yes emulator.. but it does start a new instance sometimes without the previous being closed

Comment: how do you run your program?

Comment: just normally : right click on the project --> run as --> i choose an emulator. well this problem doesn't occurs so often but sometimes. i wanted to check if there is a way not to let it happen.

Comment: At times it will.  I have this issue sometimes too.

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

1. Goto Terminal/command prompt
2. Type in `adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555`

Now the emulator will be seen as **device** to Titanium studio, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you install Genymotion to use for emulation.  Titanium Studio will see this as a device, rather than an emulator.  On the flip-side, I'm not sure if debugging works with it yet.  You may need to look for mods to make to get this working.

After installing Genymotion you select some emulators from their available list.  You'll start the Genymotion emulator yourself, rather than Titanium Studio starting it for you.  Titanium Studio's list of devices will need to be refreshed or restart Titanium Studio.  Run your project.  Titanium Studio sees the device more like a physical device, so it won't keep opening a new one on you and speed up the process a bit.

https://www.genymotion.com/

There my be a more official way to fix the Android interaction, rather than my idea of side stepping it.